# Java Play Controller Session Retrieval Understanding

Tags: java, playframework

The company I work for, use Java Play Framework. What I think mysterious is how can play retrieve the current session to me. As I see from source code,

```java
package play.mvc;

public abstract class Controller extends Results implements Status, HeaderNames {
    public static Request request() {
        return Http.Context.current().request();
    }

    public static Session session() {
        return Http.Context.current().session();
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

I found such class very strange, as all the methods are `static` methods. And I do not understand how Play can get the correct session in handling concurrent request (multi-thread environment ?).
In such case, how can Play handle / retrieve the session information correctly? Note that I can retrieve the session in the beginning or at the end of each Action (which also affect time). And in such case, how can Play retrieve the session correctly using a static method?

Or am I missing something here? It will be cool if one can tell me how Play can make such retrieval work. Thanks.

P.S. I am using quite a legacy Play Version, `Play 2.2.0` in my work place and not learning Scala yet.

Comment: Have a look at the implementation. It probably uses a ThreadLocal.